# how to make repeatable field in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, html, xml, joomla

i want to add some actions in my module, so the main task is to add field dynamically like on this picture. joomla 3 support field type @**repeatable** but joomla 2.5 don't support this field type, maybe available some other solution how i can do this.

PS: pic what i want
[image]

Thx!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">

        <name>Slider</name> 

        <files>
                <filename module="mod_slider">mod_slider.php</filename>
                <filename>mod_slider.xml</filename>
                <filename>index.html</filename>             
                <filename>helper.php</filename>
                <folder>tmpl</folder>
        </files>
        <config>
            <fields name="params">

                <fieldset name="basic">
                    <field name="slide_title" type="text" label="Slide Title" />    
                    <field name="slide_description" type="editor" label="Slide description" />
                </fieldset>
            </fields>
        </config>   
</extension>
```

Comment: i don't want many fields, will be good only one dynamic!

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: yes, you must know that pic is from internet

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type

I guess this will work for you!

here is a list of all available standard form fields:

https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

and if you want to make any custom form field type, here's the doc:

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

I used these resources a couple of months ago, and created a hybrid module which could read data both from virtuemart (categories, Products), joomla contents, joomla menu items, and also directly from module.

If you wish to implement the usage with third party components like virtuemart, that custom form field type will come in handy, you also would need to use some kind of helper php for each of them, which in case, combining them in one file will be nice! and also trickY!

I noticed you're still on J2.5! move on buddy! 
Security risks are so high! and there's also no more updates for that version! 
get to version 3.4 (latest release) at the first possible state you can!